# Accessing Scala fields without getters

Tags: scala

Migrating from Groovy to Scala, and so far loving Scala. One of the things I deeply miss about Groovy is the fact that I could define properties/fields on objects, and then just reference them without getters from other classes.

For example, in Java:

```
public class Fizz {
    private String buzz;

    public Fizz(String buzz) {
        super();

        setBuzz(buzz);
    }

    // Getters and setters for buzz
}
```

But in Groovy:

```
class Fizz {
    String buzz
}
```

Then I could reference `buzz` from a different class like so:

```
void someMethod(Fizz fizz) {
    if(fizz.buzz == "gnarly!") {
        ...
    }
}
```

However it seems that Scala doesn't behave this way, and you have to settle for this:

```
class Fizz(buzz : String) {
  ...
}

def someMethod(fizz : Fizz) : Unit = {
  if(fizz.getBuzz.eq("gnarly!")) {
    ...
  }
}
```

To make my Scala code "*Groovier*" (for this one use case) I've settled on adding "helper" methods inside some of my Scala classes:

```
class Fizz(buzz : String) {
  def buzz() : String = { this.buzz }
}
```

Which now allows me to access them like so:

```
def someMethod(fizz : Fizz) : Unit = {
  if(fizz.buzz.eq("gnarly!")) {
    ...
  }
}
```

My question: **Does Scala have any other mechanisms/devices that allow me to accomplish the above desired behavior without having to write my so-called "helper methods"?**

Comment: Please read about the case classes in Scala

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. This is on topic, is not a dupe (given the fact that I'm obviously new to Scala and might not know about things like case classes or other constructs that have been inquired about on this site before), shows research and is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it does. Take a look at this [nice](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-class-examples-constructors-case-classes-parameters) example. Depending on how you declare the parameter in the primary constructor, you get the following behaviour:

> Declaration    Getter?    Setter?
>   -----------      -------    -------
>   var               yes        yes
>   val               yes        no
>   default           no         no

Here, `default` means that you declare the class param without either `val` or `var`, as you actually do. Consequently, just by putting `val` in front of it, you would get public access to the field out of the box.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Bianca Tesila, but doesn't that still require me to prefix the field reference with `get`? So `fizz.getBuzz`? I'm looking for a way to just write `fizz.buzz`.

Comment: No, when you call `fizz.buzz` you are actually calling the internally created getter. So You don't need anything in addition to that. You can check what is generated by using javap tool.